# How to add new snippets to snipMate in VIM

Tags: vim, snipmate

Ive just started using the sniptMate plugin for VIM and love it, however, since my collection of snippets isn't huge, I'd like to be able to add new snippets dynamically rather than opening the snippets file and creating a new snippet as I am in the middle of development.

As I am coding something I realize that some specific piece of code can be saved as a snippet to save me trouble of typing the bloat code again, at this time I want to be able to add a snippet without opening the snippet file for the language I am using at the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure it's meant to be done like this but you can try calling the `MakeSnip` function from within file you're currently working on.  For example:

```
:call MakeSnip(&ft, "foo", "<foo>${1}</foo>")
```

`&ft` will pass the filetype of the file you're currently editing, `"foo"` is the trigger and `"<foo>${1}</foo>"` is the replacement text.

Of course, snippets created like this won't persist.  So why not have the snippets file open in another buffer, define new snippets there as necessary, then do:

```
:call ReloadSnippets(&ft)
```

and your new snippet will be available.  You could even define an autocmd to call the `ReloadSnippets` function when you write the snippets file.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), you can write your own snippets without polluting the original ones. To do this, add your snippets to `~/.vim/bundle/mysnippets/snippets/*.snippets`. FYI, `mysnippets` can be any name.

Moreover, it's a convention to add a `_.snippets` file in that directory where you add snippets which should be available everywhere irrespective of the filetype.

Answer (score 6):

You can put your own snippets in `~/.vim/after/snippets/` or whatever the equivalent on Windows is...  read `:h snipMate` for the filename syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Just place your own snippets (given you want to use them in all files you edit) here:

```
~/.vim/after/snippets/_.snippets
```

For example:

```
snippet test
  {"foo": "${1}", "bar": "${2}"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Snippets for Snipmate are usually stored in the ".vim" directory in the `snippets` [folder](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim/tree/master/snippets).

You can pretty easily edit the snippet file for the language you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

If you use vundle to manage your plugins on Windows and you have installed

```
vim-snipMate & vim-snippets
```

If you want to add your **customization**, say to '**html**' filetype, you just go to this folder:

```
$HOME/vimfiles/bundle/vim-snippets/snippets/
```

create a new file and name it in this format:

```
html_bsmith.snippets
```

(it must be underscore after html, see :help snipmate)

Then vim will load your file automatically.

If you customization can be used anywhere, just put it in the existing file:

```
    _.snippets
```