# Create an array with vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, code-snippets

I need a productive way of creating an (array) using vim ?

consider this example in ruby :

```
fruit = ['orange','apple','banana']
```

is there a way which would made this possible with less keystrokes ?

I need a productive way of creating an (array) using vim ?

consider this example in ruby :

```
fruit = ['orange','apple','banana']
```

is there a way which would made this possible with less keystrokes ?

Edit: Thanks to @ebenezer After doing some research I ended up using [xptemplate](https://github.com/drmingdrmer/xptemplate) which is a snippet manager for vim. if any one is interested , take a look at the `def` snippet inside python snippet file.
which is demonstrated by the author of the plugin [here](http://vimeo.com/7868048).

Comment: What do you originally have (and in which format)? How do you think can keystrokes be saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wish to look at Michael Sanders’s [snipMate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) plugin (on vim.org: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540). If it doesn’t already have a suitable snippet, you *could*, as [described in an answer to “How to add new snippets to snipMate in VIM”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7066758/758011), define your own snippet, which for the purposes of your example might be done something like

```
:call MakeSnip(&ft, "arr", "= ['${1}', '${2}']")
```

and then after entering, for example

```
def fruit arr
```

hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> would give you

```
def fruit = ['', '']
```

with your cursor placed in the first `''`, ready to fill out, and with another <kbd>Tab</kbd> moving it to the second. You might save this as your own snippet by placing it under `~/.vim/snippets` by filetype; for your Ruby example, `~/.vim/snippets/ruby/arr.snippet` could contain something like

```
= ['${1}', '${2}']
```

and you would then be enabled, when working on a file of the `ruby` filetype, to use it as described above.

Comment: would you suggest a snippets for doing that quickly ?

Comment: @static I am not familiar with Ruby or with the plugin’s support for it, but have added some examples of how such a snippet could be defined in case the plugin doesn’t already provide one.

Answer (score 2):

One way of speeding this up would be to use Tim Pope's [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin. It provides a nice insert mode mapping to create pairings of characters via `<c-s>` or `<c-g>s` depending on your terminal. Example: `<c-s>]` would create `[]` with the cursor between the brackets. You can also use it to create the strings. However surround does a bunch more. I suggest you look at its documentation.

A related plugin also provides a similar function called [delimitMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2754). However I can not comment on it as I do not personally use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do auto completion in insert mode for [] by setting following:

`:inoremap [ []<ESC>i`